# Permission denied when using SSH to connect to a remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, openssh

I am new to ssh and have it installed in two Linux machines (Ubuntu 20.04.3 and Zorin OS 16). I tried to access from one machine to the other via ssh. The command I use is `ssh username@ip-address`, but I got an error saying Permission denied despite entering the correct password. I have tried the following ways, but none of them is working.

1. Change root password and enable PermitRootLogin in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
2. Enable PasswordAuthentification
3. Reinstall ssh

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What happens when you use ssh -v to log in?  Does the username exist on both systems (ie when you ssh to username@ you are logging in as user username, not root).  What is your /etc/ssh/sshd_cinfig file ?

Answer (score 0):

The "username" in `ssh username@ip-address` is actually "root" in this case, since it seems you're trying to login as root, so that makes the command: `ssh root@ip-address`.

Also, on the remote server, make sure sshd is running. If using systemd, you can run `systemctl status ssh` or `systemctl status sshd` (sudo shouldn't be necessary for 'status') depending on distro.